# How do you change date format in ubuntu

Tags: libreoffice

The time manager in Qgis demands date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I have a large text file with the dates in DD/MM/YYYYY format.  It's too large to manually change format.  Is there any way of automating this process?  I have tried altering format in Libre office but it still stays the original format.The date format required is 2020-01-16. Human name fields removed.

```
Record ID   English Name    Grid Reference  Latitude    Longitude   Site Name   Abundance   Record Type Date    Comments    Time of sighting    Squirrel ID Weight (g)  CRST Comments
7765235 Red Squirrel    SJ0369952368    53.059853   -3.4384031  Clocaenog: Bron Branog: Location 10 1 Adult     01/10/2020      13:09           
7765230 Red Squirrel    SJ0367552319    53.059408   -3.4387464  Clocaenog: Bron Branog: Location 9  1 Adult     01/10/2020      16:54           
7761554 Red Squirrel    SH9856552277    53.058084   -3.5149526  Clocaenog: Pentre-llyn-cymmer: Location 5   1       01/10/2020      17:22           
7761417 Red Squirrel    SJ0454252299    53.059384   -3.4258081  Clocaenog: Main Block East: Location 15 1       01/10/2020      16:36           
7761416 Red Squirrel    SJ0454252299    53.059384   -3.4258081  Clocaenog: Main Block East: Location 15 1       01/10/2020      08:51           
7765217 Red Squirrel    SJ0357152125    53.057646   -3.4402395  Clocaenog: Bron Branog: Location 7  1 Adult     02/10/2020      13:42           
7765210 Red Squirrel    SJ0354052072    53.057164   -3.440686   Clocaenog: Bron Branog: Location 5  1 Sub-adult     02/10/2020      16:07           
7765209 Red Squirrel    SJ0354052072    53.057164   -3.440686   Clocaenog: Bron Branog: Location 5  1 Adult     02/10/2020  Patchy squirrel 13:54
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of input text + desired output

Comment: The file format is pretty awful, CSV would have been more useful, but with a small edit my approach still works.

Comment: Couldn't see how to add csv so pasted.  My apologies but I am not familiar with awk and how do I get to the point of entering your code please?  I do know how to use Terminal but not familiar.

Comment: it's almost going to have to be in csv form... the dates and time are separated by comments, comments that have spaces... parsing nightmare.....  Does it reside in a libreoffice file? In libreOffice you can Save As it as a csv.. then view that csv file in a terminal.... then cut and paste from there

Comment: @Vic before you go too far with this....  what did you do to change the format in libreoffice calc??? I cut and pasted the first line into calc, used one of the stock formats to format the date column and then saved it to a csv.... and in a terminal it now looks like **7765235,Red Squirrel,SJ0369952368,53.059853,-3.4384031,Clocaenog:, Bron,Branog:,
2020-01-10,Location 10 1 Adult ,01:09:00 PM,,,** ... (i mixed up the order) ...but is this all that you would need to do?

Comment: Record ID,Latitude,Longitude,Date
6492206,53.056136,-3.4327734,01/01/2020
6492202,53.056576,-3.4328029,01/01/2020
5837655,53.057969,-3.4343115,01/01/2020
5837653,53.069072,-3.422352,01/01/2020
6492201,53.056576,-3.4328029,02/01/2020
6492200,53.056576,-3.4328029,02/01/2020
6020754,53.056576,-3.4328029,02/01/2020
6020374,53.056576,-3.4328029,02/01/2020
5863349,53.069072,-3.422352,08/01/2020

Comment: A truncated paste for clarity.  I tried Libre Office format change but it always stays the same even pasting into a pre formatted cell, as I understand it the date format is controlled by the Country set in Ubuntu (UK English)

Comment: I was able to change it... it is permament in both the ODS file and the CSV i created... which process would be easier for you to end up doing... command line solution or in libreoffice if you could figure it out? I don't know what format your data comes in, so I cant tell which solution would be more beneficial... Is it a text file? and you are pasting it into a calc? or is it already in calc? or are you exporting it out of something else?

Comment: It is a calc file, command line would be preferable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115340/discussion-between-wu-tang-and-vic).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about the structure/look of your textfile I'll pretend it only has one column, the date field:

```
$ awk '{a=gensub(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/,"\\3-\\2-\\1","1",$0); print a}' file.txt
2020-02-01
```

To put that into a file (rather than on screen) redirect the output:

```
$ awk '{a=gensub(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/,"\\3-\\2-\\1","1",$0); print a}' file.txt  >new_text_file
```

Where `file.txt` is to be replaced with the name of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reformat date strings in free-form text, I'd suggest using Perl since it allows you to combine sed-style `s/pattern/replacement/` regex search-and-replace with Unix-style `strptime` and `strftime`. Ex.

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
  s;\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2};Time::Piece->strptime($&,"%Y-%m-%d")->strftime("%d/%m/%Y");ge
' yourfile
```

For columnar data, I'd probably choose Miller instead - it has a builtin `strptime`/`strftime` that you can apply on a fieldwise basis.

Answer (score 0):

The date command converts dates to whatever you dictate...

`date -d "10/28/2020" +%Y-%m-%d`
2020-10-28

.
.

```
If there is only dates in the file thedates.txt
10/28/2020
10/29/2020
11/27/2021
12/20/2020
5/6/1999
11/6/73
11/11/2011
```

...then the file can be read with the date command `date -f thedates.txt  +%Y-%m-%d`

```
2020-10-28
2020-10-29
2021-11-27
2020-12-20
1999-05-06
1973-11-06
2011-11-11 
2020-10-21<---- and if you unintentionally read something like a blank line at the end of the file.. it will translate that to today's date... dont leave blanks or parse them out.
```

If there is more than just dates in the file(likely), then you need to parse thedates.txt file with what I fear would be a `for` statement and dropping them into a variable and then running the date command on the $variable with the -d flag as above, then sending the formatted output back to the desired location....

This makes the conversion extremely simple, but the parsing makes it lumpy...
...at least for someone with my regex/scripting clumsiness. Depending on the difficulty of the not yet seen sample data, this may assist another answer if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In Calc insert new date column, format column as YYYY-MM-DD. Highlight/copy original date column but when pasting choose "Special", "Paste as unformatted text".  It then stays in desired format so you can delete original (wrongly formattted) date column. Thank you Wu-Tang for pointing me in right direction.